# Move wall drainpipe to make room for garbage disposal?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, garbage-disposal

My kitchen sink is almost centered over the wall drainpipe and there seems to be no way to arrange any connections to make room for the garbage disposal.   Before I give up and learn to live without, I wanted to check the feasibility of moving the wall drainpipe to the right to make room or possibly changing the p-trap configuration to somehow get it out from being directly under the sink drain.

Pictures hopefully explain this better than words:
[image: under the sink area]

[image: wall drainpipe]

[image: view through sink drain]

[image: another view]

[image: another drain pipe view]

I’d love any advice about what’s feasible, considering that while the back wall inside the cabinet can be opened, the cabinets and the sink are at their final location and cannot be moved.

Comment: Can you remove the galvanized nipple going into the wall and replace it with a 45 degree elbow to skirt around the disposal?  Can you use pvc for the drain work?

Comment: Agree. Try to get a 45-degree elbow in there and shift the trap off to one side and put the disposal in the center. Not ideal, but it should work.

Comment: so where you see the threads at the end of the wall waste pipe (is that what you're calling galvanized nipple?) I couldn't even nudge the attached p-trap, not to say that it's "welded" or otherwise permanently attached but I'm worried if it is, then cutting it off and threaded a new connection might be ... challenging inside the 24" wide cabinet?   Obviously I'm going to have a local licensed plumber look at it, but I wanted to know whether anything is feasible that isn't ridiculously expensive...

Comment: oh if that's a galvanized nipple going into the wall it can presumably be replaced by a shorter one?  which would then allow the elbow to need to go not as far to the side?

Comment: galvanized isn't that durable I've read - should I be replacing that with brass or whatever anyway?  The cold water valve isn't on there because some genius put a galvanized nipple on a copper pipe and it got completely corroded...

Answer (score 0):

I would be cautious that old galvanized pipe may crumble opening a big can of worms. The pipe will be rusty and difficult to remove but if you can unscrew it a shorter nipple and possibly some 45’s would allow enough space for the disposal. As far as a replacement material ABS (plastic) would be my choice much easier and cheaper to work with. I would advise to use caution because that pipe is probably 40+ years old with water and air exposure and the occasional drain cleaner it could literally crumble when you try to disassemble it.

Comment: I didn't do the work myself but rather had a plumber do it.  He cut the nipple/trap off, replace it all with new ones including a 45º elbow and now everything fits!